# How to replace dao method by mockito

Tags: java, testing, service, mockito

I have a problem when i want to change dao fuction in method **when** in mockito.

There always want get connect, and I get an error `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException`, where DAO class trying to connect with dataSource and get environment context.

```
public class OrderingMainActionTest extends Mockito {

    @Mock
    HttpSession mockedSession = mock(HttpSession.class);

    @Mock
    OrderingMainAction applicationServiceBean;

    @Mock
    InitialContext ic;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void orderingActionByUserTest() throws ServletException, IOException, AppException, SQLException {
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        OrderingMainAction ordering = new OrderingMainAction();
        UserDao userDao = mock(UserDao.class);

        when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);

        when(mockedSession.getAttribute("user")).thenReturn(user);
        when(request.getParameter("checkedSeats")).thenReturn("1");
        when(userDao.getFullNameByUserId(anyInt())).thenReturn("test test");

        assertEquals(ordering.execute(request,response),"/login");
    }

}
```

Class which i trying testing

```
public class OrderingMainAction extends Action {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OrderingMainAction.class);

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException, AppException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
            return "/login";
        }

        LOG.trace("Info ordering ticket --> "
                + " Route " + session.getAttribute("userRoute") + ", "
                + " User: " + session.getAttribute("user") + ", "
                + " Carriage Number: " + request.getParameter("checkedCarriage") + ", "
                + " Seats List: " + Arrays.toString(request.getParameter("checkedSeats").split(" ")) + ", ");

        LOG.trace("rsb:" + session.getAttribute("userRoute"));
        RouteSearchBean route = (RouteSearchBean) session.getAttribute("userRoute");

        UserCheck userCheck = new UserCheck();
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        String[] seatList = request.getParameter("checkedSeats").split(" ");
        userCheck.setIdUser(((User) session.getAttribute("user")).getId());
        try {
            userCheck.setInitials(userDao.getFullNameByUserId(
                    ((User) session.getAttribute("user")).getId())
            );
        } catch (DBException e) {
            throw new AppException(LocaleMessageUtil
                    .getMessageWithLocale(request, e.getMessage()));
        }
        userCheck.setNumCarriage(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("checkedCarriage")));
        userCheck.setIdRoute(route.getIdRoute());

        for (String numSeat : seatList) {
            for (int i = 0; i < route.getStationList().size() - 1; ++i) {
                userCheck.setDateEnd(route.getStationList().get(i).getTimeEnd());
                userCheck.setIdTrain(route.getTrain().getId());
                userCheck.setIdStation(route.getStationList().get(i).getIdStation());
                userCheck.setNumSeat(Integer.parseInt(numSeat));
                LOG.trace("INSERT for ordering --> " + userCheck);
                CheckDao.saveUserCheckInfo(userCheck);

            }
        }

        return "WEB-INF/jsp/booking/ordering.jsp";
    }
}
```

DAO Class with this problem method

```
    public String getFullNameByUserId(Integer idUser) throws DBException {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String initials = "";

        try {
            //DBUtil <-- There is a problem
            conn = DBUtil.getInstance().getDataSource().getConnection();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
```

DB Util class

```
public final class DBUtil {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DBUtil.class);

    private static DBUtil instance;

    private DataSource ds;

    public static synchronized DBUtil getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBUtil();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private DBUtil(){
        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            // Problem is here, and always throw the exception javax.naming.NoInitialContextException
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/ResConDB");
            LOG.trace("Data source ==> " + ds);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            LOG.error(Messages.ERR_CANNOT_OBTAIN_DATA_SOURCE, ex);
            //throw new DBException(Messages.ERR_CANNOT_OBTAIN_DATA_SOURCE, ex);
        }
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: Show the method under test. There is not enough context about what is being tested.

Comment: I had edited this post

Comment: At no point is the mocked dao being injected into the subject under test. At least based on the currently shown code.

Comment: `OrderingMainAction` appears to be the subject under test. How does it make use of  `UserDao`

Comment: Sorry, but now i had edited this post again and add class which use dao.

Comment: The main question and problem is how to replace this dao by 'when', in order to do not use dao in service

Comment: I understand the problem. I needed to see where you were using the dao in order to see where your setup was wrong. checking that now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the subject method under test and the assertion, it appears you are trying to mock a lot of unnecessary dependencies.

the shown assertion

```
assertEquals(ordering.execute(request,response),"/login");
```

expects to receive `"/login"`, which would only occur if the following condition

```
//...

if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
    return "/login";
}

//...
```

behaves as expected.

A test to satisfy the above condition would have to look like

```
public class OrderingMainActionTest {

    @Test
    public void orderingActionByUserTest() throws ServletException, IOException, AppException, SQLException {
        //Arrange
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpSession mockedSession = mock(HttpSession.class);    
        when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);   
        when(mockedSession.getAttribute("user")).thenReturn(null);

        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

        string expected = "/login";
        OrderingMainAction ordering = new OrderingMainAction();

        //Act
        String actual = ordering.execute(request, response);

        //Assert
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

Which leads me to believe that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that requires more clarification.

Comment: I know, that this kind of satisfied this problem, but here is other problem, when "user" is not null, i need replace dao, but I always get error message about NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property... Maybe, this is Tomcat problem or my DataSource connection Pool

Comment: @Anatol' check https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects. It will show you how to mock the dao. right now the actual object is being used and not the mock, which is why it is trying to make the connection.

Comment: @Anatol' I however foresee you encountering more issues as you have other objects that need to be mocked.